# How to export .tif image in Mathematica that can be read correctly by ParaView

Tags: export

I wanted to visualise image in ParaView but before that, I need to process image in Mathematica. However, I found when the image exported as different format in Mathematica is imported into ParaView, it will show different result.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Collagenimage = Import["Roi 1 a0.tif", "BitDepth" -> 8];
Export["1.tif", Collagenimage]
Export["2.tif", Collagenimage, "BitDepth" -> 8]
```

Import original collagen image with bit 8 into ParaView:
[image][image]

Import 1.tif image with bit 16 into ParaView:
[image][image]

Import 2.tif image with bit 8 into ParaView:
[image][image]

According to the Data Arrays in ParaView, it seems that image exported from Mathematica will lose pixel values. I am not sure whether this is the reason why the image cannot display normally. Could anyone please give some suggestions? Does anyone know how to avoid this situation?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Since your question involves another piece of software, you will have to wait for a reply from someone who has had direct experience with it. Can you confirm that you can read Mma generated tif files in another software on your system using the usual software such as GIMP or Paint etc. Also use `$Version` to include version info and your OS information. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Syed, thanks for your suggestions. tif files generated in Mma can display correctly in Paint software. My version is "13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)".